# making automatically sorted insert function

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef int element;
typedef struct ListNode {
    element data;
    struct ListNode *link;
} ListNode;

ListNode *temp;

int get_length(ListNode *nodetype) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; nodetype != NULL; i++) {
        nodetype = nodetype->link;
    }
    return i;
}

void add(ListNode *listtype, element elementtype){
    listtype = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    listtype->data= elementtype;
    listtype = listtype->link;
}


void display(ListNode *nodetype) {
    for (int i=0; nodetype != NULL; i++) {
        printf("%d ", nodetype->data);
        nodetype = nodetype->link;
    }
}

int main() {
    ListNode *list1=NULL;

    add(list1, 3);
    add(list1, 3);

    printf("%d\n", get_length(list1));
    display(list1);
}
```

when i have three factor (ListNode **phead, ListNode *p, ListNode *new_node), program didn't make any error. but i have to use only 'list' factor and 'item' factor to obey original requirement. because 'get_length' function and 'display' function work well previous codes, i think 'add' function seems to have mistake. 
i have to make sorted insert function 'add' to solve the problem.

Comment: Remember that C passes all arguments *by value*. Which means the pointer `list1` from the `main` function will be *copied* into the `listtype` argument. Modifying a copy will not modify the original. Begin with thinking about that obvious error.

Comment: did you mean i should modify list1 to &list1 in main function?

Comment: Let's be blunt. You need to pass the pointer to the first element in the linked list by reference. In C, that means a pointer to a pointer. So, your `add()` function should have prototype `add(Listnode **list, element)`. And yes, you'd then call `add(&list1, 2); add(&list2, 3);` in `main()`. In the function, you must not accept `list == NULL`, because that means the caller did not provide any reference to a list. The pointer to the first element in the function is then `(*list)`, and you can modify it. Remember to also check if `malloc()` fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:**

I haven't test this code and I haven't code in C for a long time.

**Description**

First, lets fix your add function.

It should check if your list is empty and add a new node if does. If the list is not empty, then it should traverse it until finding the last node, create a new node, and attach it at the end of it.

```
void add(ListNode *listNode, element data){

    // The list is non-existent! Create it.
    if (listNode == null){
        // Create new node
        ListNode* newNode = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->link = null;
        listNode = newNode;
        return;
    }

    // We always want to ensure that the pointer to the first element
    // of your list doesn't get override. 
    // Therefore, we create a new pointer which hold that address. 
    ListNode *currentNode = listNode;

    // Traverse the linked list until finding last element.
    while(currentNode->link != null){
        currentNode = currentNode->Link; 
    }

    // Create new node
    ListNode* newNode = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->link = null;

    // Attach new node to linked list
    currentNode->link = newNode;
}
```

Now that we fixed your add method, we can create the logic for your insert method which is similar to your add method but with the ordered logic.

Pretty much, we create the list if doesn't exist. We iterate thorough the list until we reach the end of it or an element with the data we are searching for. If we find the data, then we set that node as temp (so we don't lose it), point the link of the new node to the temp node, and the link of the current node to the new node. If we reached the end of the list and didn't find the data, then we add the new node at the end of the list.

```
void insert(ListNode *listNode, element data){

    // The list is non-existent! Create it.
    if (listNode == null){
        // Create new node
        ListNode* newNode = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->link = null;
        listNode = newNode;
        return;
    }

    // We always want to ensure that the pointer to the first element
    // of your list doesn't get override. 
    // Therefore, we create a new pointer which hold that address. 
    ListNode *currentNode = listNode;

    // Traverse the linked list until finding last element.
    // Play here with >=, >, =<, <, or any other order combination.
    while(currentNode->link != null
          && currentNode->data < data){
        currentNode = currentNode->link; 
    }

    // Create new node
    ListNode* newNode = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->link = null;

    // insert in the correct position
    if (currentNode->link != null){
        ListNode* tempNode = currentNode->link;
        currentNode->link = tempNode;
        currentNode->link = newNode;
        return;
    }

    // Attach new node to linked list
    currentNode->link = newNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the items mentioned in comments under your post, there are a few other necessary modifications required as well:

In the `add(.,.)` function, to create a new link change your original from:

```
void add(ListNode *listtype, element elementtype){
    listtype = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    listtype->data= elementtype;
    listtype = listtype->link;
}
```

To:

```
//create new link in function: newNode, modify its members,
//then set original listtype == newNode 
void add(ListNode **listtype, element elementtype)
{
    ListNode *newNode = calloc(1, sizeof (*newNode));  // add this new Node
    if(newNode)//test that calloc is successful
    {
        newNode->data = elementtype;
        newNode->link = *listtype;//these lines 
        (*listtype) = newNode;    //add new link to original
    }
}
```

Also, in the `get_length()` function, change the following line:

```
nodetype->link = nodetype;
```

To:

```
nodetype = nodetype->link;
```

And finally, in `main`, Change:

```
int main() {
    ListNode *list1=NULL;

    add(list1, 3);
    add(list1, 3);
```

To:

```
int main(void) { //Note minimum signature of main function
    ListNode *list1=NULL;

    add(&list1, 3);//pass address of object, not object itself
    add(&list1, 3);
```